# what causes different in array sum along axis for C versus F ordered arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, row-major-order, column-major-order

I am curious if anyone can explain what exactly leads to the discrepancy in this particular handling of C versus Fortran ordered arrays in `numpy`.  See the code below:

```
system:
Ubuntu 18.10
Miniconda python 3.7.1
numpy 1.15.4
```

```
def test_array_sum_function(arr):
    idx=0
    val1 = arr[idx, :].sum()
    val2 = arr.sum(axis=(1))[idx]
    print('axis sums:', val1)
    print('          ', val2)
    print('    equal:', val1 == val2)
    print('total sum:', arr.sum())

n = 2_000_000
np.random.seed(42)
rnd = np.random.random(n)

print('Fortran order:')
arrF = np.zeros((2, n), order='F')
arrF[0, :] = rnd
test_array_sum_function(arrF)

print('\nC order:')
arrC = np.zeros((2, n), order='C')
arrC[0, :] = rnd
test_array_sum_function(arrC)
```

prints:

```
Fortran order:
axis sums: 999813.1414744433
           999813.1414744079
    equal: False
total sum: 999813.1414744424

C order:
axis sums: 999813.1414744433
           999813.1414744433
    equal: True
total sum: 999813.1414744433
```

Comment: This is weird. If I adjust your code to sum along the other axis, the discrepancy disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a consequence of numpy sometimes using [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) and [sometimes not](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8786#issuecomment-286864207).

Let's build a diagnostic array:

```
eps = (np.nextafter(1.0, 2)-1.0) / 2
1+eps+eps+eps
# 1.0
(1+eps)+(eps+eps)
# 1.0000000000000002

X = np.full((32, 32), eps)
X[0, 0] = 1
X.sum(0)[0]
# 1.0
X.sum(1)[0]
# 1.000000000000003
X[:, 0].sum()
# 1.000000000000003
```

This strongly suggests that 1D arrays and contiguous axes use pairwise summation while strided axes in a multidimensional array don't.

Note that to see that effect the array has to be large enough, otherwise numpy falls back to ordinary summation.

Comment: after a discussion with one of the numpy devs this is the correct explanation.  I was in a bad situation where I was using 32-bit floating point numbers, and summing millions of them with naive sums, which led to very large rounding errors in my case.  Putting the link here as others may find it helpful if they run into the same thing: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13240

Answer (score 1):

Floating point math isn't necessarily [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Nonassociativity_of_floating_point_calculation), i.e. `(a+b)+c != a+(b+c)`.

Since you're adding along different axes, the order of operations is different, which can affect the final result. As a simple example, consider the matrix whose sum is 1.

```
a = np.array([[1e100, 1], [-1e100, 0]])
print(a.sum())   # returns 0, the incorrect result
af = np.asfortranarray(a)
print(af.sum())  # prints 1
```

(Interestingly, `a.T.sum()` still gives 0, as does `aT = a.T; aT.sum()` , so I'm not sure how exactly this is implemented in the backend)

The C order is using the sequence of operations (left-to-right) `1e100 + 1 + (-1e100) + 0` whereas the Fortran order uses `1e100 + (-1e100) + 1 + 0`. The problem is that `(1e100+1) == 1e100` because floats don't have enough precision to represent that small difference, so the `1` gets lost.

In general, don't do equality testing on floating point numbers, instead compare using a small epsilon (`if abs(float1 - float2) < 0.00001` or `np.isclose`). If you need arbitrary float precision, use the `Decimal` library or fixed-point representation and `int`s.

Comment: `a.T` is a `view` of `a`, same databuffer, just different shapes and strides; effectively changing from `C` to `F` order.  For `sum()` I imagine it just sums databuffer, without regard to nd order.